# aws security groups - group to group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi have issues with securithy groups on aws.

Assume I have two sec groups:

```
    sg-d774eeed (secA)
    sg-d787eady (secB)
```

I want secA to have access to port 9999 on secB.

In the source input box I will add sg-d774eeed with port 9999.

Commit the changes.

Nothing works

So I need to input sg-d774eeed/0 sg-d774eeed/32 or something like that?

Comment: Are these groups in the same region?

Comment: When you are accessing SecB are you using internal IPs from SecA? If you still use the public IP, it won't work.

Comment: When connecting between instances, you need to use the internal ip or public DNS (public DNS will resolve to internal ip within aws)

Answer (score 0):

You can create just one security group with port `9999`, enter the same security group name in the source and assign this security group to both instances that you want to communicate together. However, to make that happen, you need to use either Private IP i.e. `172.1.2.3` or Public DNS i.e. `ec2-54-1-2-3.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

```
Port Range    Source
9999          sg-abcdef
```

The best is to use Public DNS because: 
*When an EC2 instance queries the external DNS name of an Elastic IP, the EC2 DNS server returns the internal IP address of the instance to which the Elastic IP address is currently assigned.*